# How to change the colour of a databound html item at runtime?

Tags: c#, javascript, colors

I have some html which displays data from my database. Shown below is a line of code that shows if an item is enabled. What I would like to do is set its colour so that it is green when enabled and red when disabled. Can I add some javascript to this line to do this?

```
<asp:Label ID="ifmgr_ase_enabled" runat="server" Text="<%# DataAdapter.Enabled.ToString() %>" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use javascript. You can do it during html generation like this:

`Style="color:<%# DataAdapter.Enabled ? 'green' : 'red' %>"`

just off the top of my head with no compilation guarantees :)

Comment: Looks like it should work but at runtime no colour is applied :(

Comment: How does the html tag look in the code after this was applied? Any obvious errors?

Comment: No colour is applied to the text. The text is shown as if I hadn't added your code. No page errors are shown.

Comment: I changed the "Style" part to the following which works. forecolor ="<%# DataAdapter.Enabled ? System.Drawing.Color.Green : System.Drawing.Color.Red %>". Needs the full path for the colours though.